# Is there a way to run a .lua file on a webserver from a .lua that isn't?

Tags: lua

I'm looking for a way to create a .lua that is a "loader" of sorts. I'm wondering if there is a way to create a .lua on a web server that contains for example:

```
file_1.lua -- on webserver

local function print_hello()
    print("hello!")
end
```

and have a separate .lua file that is not on the web server, that can access, return and run the contents of file_1.lua as if it was the original file_1.lua file.

```
file_2.lua -- not on webserver

hello!
```

Any help is appreciated! If this question is unclear, I will try to clear it up as much as I can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If `file_2.lua` is not on the web server, where is it? The web browser's machine?

Comment: I am using Lua as CGI  for Apache 2. From this point of view i like to say: Yes you can - But what sense make this? The Lua CGI producing HTML/CSS that makes only sense in a Webbrowser.  Another trap could be: The environment of a Webserver ( like the querystring ) is not available on bash environment level of an external calling Lua script.

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi - Try to read `$QUERY_STRING` env var from Lua CGI script.

Comment: @Egor i mean: Thats working for the CGI called in a Webbrowser but not for the external Lua script that do call the Lua CGI script directly without the Webservers environment. The QUERY_STRING is only an Example. More fails follows if the script try read/write cookies.

Answer (score 1):

To get the source code of a Lua file over HTTP you have to extend Lua in some way.
On Linux it is relative simple to extend Lua with a function that is able to store the output of a Linux command in a Lua variable...

```
local cmd=function(shell)
return io.popen(shell, 'r'):read('a+')
end
```

Then, on a Linux Shell, find a command to output the contents of a delivered file from a webserver.
I find `wget` ;-) ...

```
wget -q -O- localhost/file_1.lua
```

My suggest now is to tune `file_1.lua` to...

```
--[[
This file defining function(s) and return all in a table
]]

local function print_hello()
    print("hello!")
end

return {print_hello=print_hello}
```

Then a loader is simply done with...

```
package.preload.weblua=load(cmd('wget -q -O- localhost/file_1.lua'),'Hello Example')
```

You can use `require()` now...

```
weblua=require('weblua')
```

...play around with, try a...

```
weblua.print_hello()
```

The direct way, if `file_1.lua` was changed/extended (during a very long script runtime?) is to call the loader directly.
Also a single function it return in that table.
With...

```
package.preload.weblua().print_hello()
```